# TypeScript & React Native: Using Pick<T, K> to avoid bloating my code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have the following interface and React Native component that uses it:

```
import { KeyboardTypeOptions, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

export interface ValidatedInputProps {
    autoCapitalize?: 'none' | 'sentences' | 'words' | 'characters',
    contentType: Pick<TextInputProps, 'textContentType'>,
    isSecure?: boolean,
    keyboard?: KeyboardTypeOptions,
    label: string,
}

export const ValidatedInput = ({
    autoCapitalize = 'none',
    contentType,
    isSecure = false,
    keyboard = 'default',
    label,
}: ValidatedInputProps) => {
    return (
        <TextInput
            textContentType={contentType} <-- Error is flagged here
            ...other props
        />
    );
};
```

This gives me the following error popup in VSCode:

```
Type 'Pick<TextInputIOSProps, "textContentType">' is not assignable to type '"none" | "name" | "URL" | "addressCity" | "addressCityAndState" | "addressState" | "countryName" | "creditCardNumber" | "emailAddress" | "familyName" | "fullStreetAddress" | ... 17 more ... | undefined'.
  Type 'Pick<TextInputIOSProps, "textContentType">' is not assignable to type '"oneTimeCode"'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1250, 5): The expected type comes from property 'textContentType' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<TextInputProps, "textContentType" | "clearButtonMode" | "clearTextOnFocus" | "dataDetectorTypes" | "enablesReturnKeyAutomatically" | ... 114 more ... | "dense"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'
(JSX attribute) textContentType?: "none" | "name" | "URL" | "addressCity" | "addressCityAndState" | "addressState" | "countryName" | "creditCardNumber" | "emailAddress" | "familyName" | "fullStreetAddress" | ... 17 more ... | undefined
```

I'm obviously completely misunderstanding the point of the `Pick<T, K>` type, but everything that I've read on the subject over the past two hours seems to imply that my usage is correct. So what am I missing?

I guess I could define my `contentType` prop with the correct union (as I've done with `autoCapitalize`), but who would want to bloat their code with that excessively-long string of characters, when it's already been defined elsewhere?! Can't I just import that property/type and be done with it??

Comment: pls share reproducable example with all imports

Comment: I think `ValidatedInputProps` should extend `Pick<TextInputIOSProps, 'textContentType'>` and then add the extra props that are not on the  `TextInputIOSProps` interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pick<Type, Keys>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

> Constructs an Object type by picking the set of property `Keys` (string literal or union of string literals) from `Type`.

So it is *not* giving you the union of [allowed values for `textContentType`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6ba939c079796edae8dba82a0c4fe253728aada2/types/react-native/index.d.ts#L1250), but an Object type with a single key of `textContentType`.

Instead you could extend a *Picked* version of `TextInputProps` with the properties you need, then add your own properties to the interface.

```
import { KeyboardTypeOptions, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';

interface ValidatedInputProps extends Pick<TextInputProps, 'textContentType' | 'autoCapitalize'>  {
  isSecure?: boolean,
  keyboard?: KeyboardTypeOptions,
  label: string,
}
```

---

Alternatively you could just create local types by accessing each known property from the imported Object type.

```
import { KeyboardTypeOptions, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';

type myTextContentType = TextInputProps['textContentType']
type myAutoCapitalize = TextInputProps['autoCapitalize']

interface ValidatedInputProps {
  textContentType?: myTextContentType,
  autoCapitalize?: myAutoCapitalize,
  isSecure?: boolean,
  keyboard?: KeyboardTypeOptions,
  label: string,
}
```

Comment: Awesome! TYVM :D I'm going to bed now but will test this in the morning and accept it if it works. Not doubting you, but I just want to make sure. Thanks again!

Comment: Your second suggestion works well indeed! Thanks again :D